# Choose an element from a std::vector other than the given element

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I have a std::vector of strings say

```
    std::vector<std::string> MyVect = {
     "CIRCLE","SQUARE","RECTANGLE","TRIANGLE","LINE"
    };
```

And I am generating a string. My question is if the generated string is "SQUARE", the code should choose any element other than "SQUARE" from MyVect(like choosing CIRCLE or RECTANGLE or TRIANGLE but not SQUARE).

I am very new to cocos2d-x and c++.
Please Help!
Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what "the code should choose any element other than" means? Deleting the matching element? Create a new vector with the desired elements?

Comment: It should not delete any element, should only choose any one element from the given vector but not the given element(here square). Like choosing a mismatch element

Comment: Like the first element in the vector that is not the generated string?

Comment: A generated string will be anything from the same or similar vector. It may be any element from the same vector

Comment: I don't think there any particular solution to this problem in C++. You solve this in C++ in the same way as in any other language.

Comment: In C++ it is: `std::string s="SQUARE";`, [`*std::find_if_not(MyVect.begin(), MyVect.end(), [&](const auto &e){return e==s;});`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if_not/)

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thanks a lot! This is what I exactly need.

Answer (score 1):

// Then Out vector should have elements other than the string generated.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

std::string generated = "SQUARE";
std::vector<std::string> MyVect = {
     "CIRCLE","SQUARE","RECTANGLE","TRIANGLE","LINE"
    };

std::vector<std::string> OutputVect;

for (auto str : MyVect )
{
   if( str != generated)
   {
     OutputVect.push_back(str);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to keep another vector of ints *choicesUsed* and every time you select a random element, add the vector index to it. Then when next choosing your random element, ignore any choices where the index you've selected is inside your choicesUsed vector.

Comment: This may not work as I am doing random_shuffle to the vector on each iteration

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function template provided by the `<algorithm>` header like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>

std::string generated = "...";

const auto firstNonEqual = std::find_if(MyVec.cbegin(), MyVec.cend(),
    [&generated](const auto& element){ return element != generated; });

assert(firstNonEqual != MyVec.cend());

std::cout << "selected: " << *firstNonEqual << "\n";
```